# How to invoke PDF url in external browser or within iframe tag on android/ios devices

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2

How to invoke PDF url in external browser or within iframe tag on android/ios devices

Technology:

- Cordova CLI: 7.0.1
- Ionic Framework Version: 3.4.2
- Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.1
- Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.7
- Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.3.7
- Node Version: v6.10.1

Problem:

1. When trying to launch PDF from android/ios application (firebase storage download url) into external browser for some reason instead of opening pdf file in browser it downloads on device. However same code works in browser but not on device (android,ios):  `window.open('PDFURL','_system','location=yes');`
2. When trying to launch PDF from android/ios application (firebase storage download url) using IFRAME, it does not render page at all. Again this also works inside browser directly.

I can see correct URL in console.log and message `Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/pdf:`

Comment: You know, your question doesn't actually contain any *question* -- just statements.